# Kinematic meaning of this mean value theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, differential-geometry, kinematics

Here is another version of the mean value theorem :

Let $f,g,h$ three real functions continue on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $]a,b[$.

We define $\phi(x) = \begin{vmatrix}
 f(a) & f(b) & f(x)\\
 g(a) & g(b) & g(x)\\
 h(a) & h(b) & h(x)
 \end{vmatrix}$

and show that there exists $c\in ]a,b[$ such that $\phi'(c)=0$.

**But I was wondering what was the kinematic meaning of this theorem for the following motion : $t \mapsto M(t)=(f(t),g(t),h(t))$ ?**

**Is it possible to have a drawing of the situation ?**

The nullity of the determinant means that the three vectors are in the same plane.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I think you intend "kinematic" ("moving") in English.

Comment: The existence of $c$ follows because $|\phi|$ must have a maximum on the closed interval $[a,b]$. So you're finding the parallelepiped of maximum (unsigned) volume spanned by the vectors $M(a), M(x), M(b)$.

Comment: I don't follow your argument. If you apply the mean value theorem separately, you end up with three different $c$'s.

Comment: @TedShifrin My mistake I applied the Rolle's theorem which gives $\phi(a)=\phi(b)=0$ ! But the question of this post concerns the "kinematic meaning".

Comment: Ok... Why is there a downvote...

Answer (score 0):

Slightly reinterpreting my previous comment, for any $c$ with $\phi'(c)=0$, $M(c)$ will give you a point on the curve $\{M(t)\}$ where the height of the curve over the plane spanned by $M(a)$ and $M(b)$ has a critical point. In particular, one of those critical points gives the point of maximal distance from that plane.

Comment: Thank you for answering. If I understand, we know that for $c$ we have $\phi'(c)=0$ which means that the speed vector of $M$ for $t=c$ belongs to the plane spanned by $M(a)$ and $M(b)$. Then this speed vector is orthogonal to $M(c)$ (why ?). If so, $M(c)$ is orthogonal to $M(a)$ and $M(b)$ in particular. That is why $M(c)$ represents the maximum height from the plane ?

Comment: No, $M(c)$ is not necessarily orthogonal to the plane. I'm deducing my claim immediately from the fact that the volume of the parallelepiped is the area of its base times its height. You can also reason by seeing that $\phi(t) = M(t)\cdot (M(a)\times M(b)$. Remember that $M(a)\times M(b)$ is a vector orthogonal to the plane spanned by $M(a)$ and $M(b)$.

Comment: Is it possible to have a drawing of the situation ?